# Box2d sensor interact

Tags: box2d

Is there a way to make two box2d sensors, attached to different bodies, interact with each other? I don't want to make them usual fixtures because they should pass through everything and just detect collisions with other fixtures and similar sensors.

If sensors can't interact at all, is there some good way to receive an event through b2ContactListener about overlapping shapes but letting them to pass through everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Justas Sakalauskas is just plain *wrong*. Sensors are made exactly for that purpose. They detect collisions/overlaps just like normal fixtures, but they are basically like "ghost" fixtures. Upon collision they do **not** result in any kind of force being applied to the colliding fixtures to push them apart.

Thus they perfectly fit your use case and they are used this way by many others as well.

Comment: Yup, you are probably right, I misunderstood "interact with each other" part.

Comment: You are right. The real problem was not in sensors not interacting with other sensors but in edge shapes not interacting with each other. I solved this problem by setting them not as line, but as box with one dimension zeroed. It's somewhat weird, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so sorry for some misunderstanding. If you'r question is how to make two fixtures not collide but still receive beginContact then sensors are the way to go.  In beginContact you just check isSensor flag of fixture and you are good to go.

Comment: The problem is that using collision filtering causes fixtures to either don't collide at all and generate no BeginContact or to collide, generate BeginContact and be pushed apart to not overlap. I want to allow them to overlap but still generate BeginContact

Comment: Then how about using collision filter determine if two fixtures shouldn't collide set collision flag to false and call the beginContact method yourself.

Comment: Weird--I was just about to ask this question. Good suggestion, Justas. Quite roundabout, but effective. But I'll have to disagree with you on your declaration that "that's why they're called sensors". Sensors sense; they should sense each other as well.